# Getting "illegal start to an expression" error in Java

Tags: java, class, computer-science

I am working on some code for my cs12300 class. The program says that line 21 `private String RecordSales()` and is "an illegal start to an expression". This causes the file to be unable to compile. How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Concert
{
  public static void main (String args[]);
  {
    int capacity; 
    int soldByPhone; 
    int soldAtVenue; 
    int totalSalesAmount; 
    int costOfVenue=30; 
    int costOfPhone=35; 

    private String RecordSales() 
    { 
      int totalsales=changePhoneSalestoVenueSales(soldByPhone);
      int total=soldAtVenue+soldByPhone;
      int rtickets=remainingTickets(total);
      return totalsales+" "+rtickets+" "+total; 
    }

    int remainingTickets(int total)
    { 
      return capacity-total;
    }

    int changePhoneSalestoVenueSales(int soldByPhone2) 
    { 
      return soldAtVenue*costOfVenue+soldByPhone2*costOfPhone; 
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {  
      Concert c=new Concert();  
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
      System.out.println("capacity of the venue:"); 
      c.capacity=sc.nextInt(); 
      System.out.println("Number of ticketsbsold at the venue:"); 
      c.soldAtVenue=sc.nextInt(); 
      System.out.println("Number of tickets sold by phone:"); 
      c.soldByPhone=sc.nextInt(); 
      System.out.println("Total Sales: Remaining tickets: Ticket sold:"); 
      System.out.println("$"+c.RecordSales());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please consider using an IDE  (Eclipse, Netbeans, ....) it will help you to validate the syntax ..

Answer (score 1):

For a start, you have two main methods, one of which ends in a semicolon. Try getting rid of that top main method, as the rest of the syntax looks acceptable. The reason you're getting that error is because you are defining a method within the body of a method, which in Java is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out and being nice bout it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Wow... so much is wrong there. :-)

My first suggestion would be to use an IDE. That'll give you a lot of guidance about the basic syntax while you learn the language.

Specifically you have a half-written main method at the top which looks like a mistake from a cut-and-paste operation. Get rid of it and the opening semi-colon that follows it; that's preventing the compiler from understanding what the hell you are talking about with the rest of the class.

Comment: i'm sorry i offended you with my lack of knowledge???? i mean at least i'm trying right? :/

Comment: You didn't offend. Hence the smiley face. It's great that you are learning Java. As I and others have said, if you find an IDE to use, you will get up to speed with the basic syntax much more quickly. It will guide you and give you immediate (instant) feedback on what's wrong. That gives you a much quicker ["Huh???" to "Ohh!"] cycle than asking your question here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should start by removing lines 5-6:

```
public static void main (String args[]);
{
```